# HDMI Output works with NOOBS but not after I install an OS

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, noobs

I am brand new to RasPi. 
I installed the NOOBS onto an SD card. (formatted using SDFormatter)
On boot the NOOBS screen came up on HDMI.
I selected Raspbian. 
After NOOBS installed Raspbian and (I assume) booted the OS there was no HDMI.
Now when I boot I do get HDMI until it gets past the screen telling me to push Shift to configure. If I let it go on to boot the OS the HDMI disappears. If I hold shift then HDMI remains active and I get the NOOBS screen.

I have worked through the suggestions on FAQs at http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs
Any other suggestions gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same problem, check *linquize* solution: [Blank screen after installing Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/blank-screen-after-installing-raspbian)

In short, the problem is that the config-file is overwritten by the template. You could try to let it finish the boot-process, and with no signal on the HDMI, try to connect to the Pi via SSH. Then edit /boot/config.txt and uncomment these to:

```
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

An other solution is to install [Raspbian directly on the SD card](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup), without using NOOBS. After it's installed on the SD, mount the SD card on a Linux-box and edit the /boot/config.txt as above, before booting it up on the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the similar issue. I looked into it, but unfortunately I was not able to remote in with SSH either. There was not even a link light on the network. I gave up on NOOBS and made an SD card with Raspbian. That works just fine.