# In Noobs, screen works, but cannot boot raspbian

Tags: raspbian, boot, noobs

As new raspberry pi user, I'm a bit confused. I have the following setup:

- Raspberry Pi B model
- Philips 273E3QH screen with HDMI input, with an HDMI cable to my Raspberry Pi
- SanDisk Extreme Pro card

I downloaded Noobs 1.3, copied the files to the SD card and powered my Raspberry Pi. Screen works fine, and I can select the OS's I want to install. I select Raspbian, after which the installer says the installation was successful. However, when trying to reboot, the screen stays black. I mean, it is not inactive (the backlight of the screen is active, so it appears to light up completely but faintly), but after that nothing.

So, my screen directly connected to the HDMI was able to deal with the installer, but nothing happens when actually trying to boot raspbian.

Anyone an idea? I unsuccessfully tried to change settings in the config.txt, and I also verified the ext2 partitions. These were clean. On the other hand, I didn't check the fat16 boot partition yet of 60 Mb for errors (before and after this boot partition, there are unallocated partitions of 4Mb).

Any leads would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Filip

Comment: Take a look at this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10210/hdmi-output-works-with-noobs-but-not-after-i-install-an-os

Comment: have you tried connecting it over SSH ?

Comment: I didn't think SSH was enabled by default on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Press the numnber 1 or 2 key on your keyboard durring bootup, it will select which output to use , i forget what all the options are, but i know the first numbers 1 and 2 are for hdmi and 3 and 4 are for the ntsc / pal i think...